# Only ping works on IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

Recently one of my servers got an IPv6 address. However, only ping seems to work on IPv6:

```
#  ping6 google.com
PING google.com(fra16s24-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra16s24-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.37 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.374/1.374/1.374/0.000 ms

# nc google.com 80 -6vvv
nc: connect to google.com port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

Network configuration looks like this:

```
iface ens18 inet6 static
address 2a00:12d8:2008:2ffc:0000:0000:0000:0001
netmask 64

post-up /sbin/ip -r route add 2a00:12d8:2008::1 dev ens18
post-up /sbin/ip -r route add default via 2a00:12d8:2008::1
```

It's probably unlikely that there's a firewall somewhere that blocks anything but ICMP packets. Could this be some kind of misconfiguration on my side? What can I do to debug such an issue?

Update:
Yes, this happens with all destinations, not only Google.

```
# traceroute6 -Snp80 google.com
traceroute6: invalid option -- 'S'
Usage: traceroute6 [-dnrvV] [-m max_ttl] [-p port#] [-q nqueries]
        [-s src_addr] [-t tos] [-w wait] host [data size]
# traceroute6 -np80 google.com
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:4001:824::200e) from 2a00:12d8:2008:2ffc::1, 30 hops max, 24 byte packets
 1  2a00:12d8:200e::2  0.718 ms  0.42 ms  0.427 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
...
# traceroute6 -n google.com
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:4001:824::200e) from 2a00:12d8:2008:2ffc::1, 30 hops max, 24 byte packets
 1  2a00:12d8:200e::2  0.589 ms  0.396 ms  0.396 ms
 2  2a00:12d8:2008::1  0.83 ms  0.815 ms  0.688 ms
 3  2001:7f8:33::a100:6939:1  0.735 ms  0.7 ms  0.66 ms
 4  2001:7f8::3b41:0:1  1.26 ms  1.321 ms  1.222 ms
 5  2001:4860:0:1::19ef  1.347 ms  1.218 ms  1.415 ms
 6  2001:4860:0:1::1af7  1.477 ms  1.347 ms  1.231 ms
 7  2a00:1450:4001:824::200e  1 ms  0.98 ms  1.181 ms
```

Comment: When ICMP works and TCP doesn't I always think of asymmetric routing somewhere. Worth a look?

Comment: Comparing the output of `traceroute6 -Snp80 google.com` and `traceroute6 -n google.com` may provide some hints. It is also relevant to know whether you observe the same problem with other destinations than Google.

Comment: @kasperd I updated the information in the question.

Comment: Looks like your hosting provider has a very broken firewall.

Comment: Let's see what they say

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the end the solution was really simple:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
```

And to make it permanent:

```
echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

From the manual:

> This enables global IPv6 forwarding between all interfaces.

Honestly I have no idea why this has to be activated but it did solve the issue for me.

Comment: I'd say you might be receiving returning packets on a different interface from the one you are sending them. A tcpdump specifying the interface with "-i *interfacename*" should help.

Comment: I absolutely cannot see any meaningful connection between the symptoms described in the question and this answer.

Comment: Yes, me neither.